# What happens when you roll zero or negative damage?

Tags: damage, pathfinder-2e-playtest

If a Kobold Dragon Mage (*Pathfinder Playtest Bestiary*, p. 83) hits a character with its staff, it does 1d4–2 damage. If a 2 is rolled on the die, how much damage is dealt? What if a 1 is rolled on the die?

In both these cases in 1st-edition Pathfinder, the result would be 1 nonlethal damage, but I could find no answer to this question in the *Pathfinder Playtest Rulebook*.

Answer (score 3):

### We believe the minimum damage is 0

As noted under **Resistance**:

> A creature with resistance reduces damage dealt to it by
>   the amount listed in its resistance entry (to a minimum of
>   0 damage).

Which is the most common way to get your damage reduced in the game. But otherwise, there is no mention of minimum damage in the rules, and the community assumes this omission will be addressed in the final release of the rules.

Note that they also forgot to explain how this works when you are under the *Enfeebled* condition, which also lowers your damage done.

Comment: Could you add sources to establish this as a community consensus?

Comment: @ifusaso. There is no point, just search those keywords at paizo forums, many people have asked this. I would just wait for the final release.